# Parsing AND and OR condition statement based on a parentheses in javascript/angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parsing, binary-operators

Ok so basically, I have a statement as such;

```
$scope.promotion = "((A|B)|(C|D)) & (E | ((F|G) & (H|I))) & (J | K)";
```

is it possible to separate this string based on the parentheses's? so that i get a return as such;

```
$scope.promo1 = "(A|B)";
$scope.promo2 = "(C|D)";
$scope.promo3 = "((A|B) | (C|D))";
```

something like this.

Comment: Understand that `|` and `&` are binary operators, not logical operators. Why the "string-operations" tag?

Comment: my bad, still new to this, thanks for the input, will change it accordingly!

Comment: In JavaScript, Regular Expressions can be used to extract strings from text. See [MDN JavaScript Guide -- Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: Also see [Abstract Descent Parser algorithm implemented in JavaScript](https://github.com/ericbn/js-abstract-descent-parser).

Comment: thanks for the response, @georgeawg truly appreciated, i've tried using RegEx too, but the thing is, when it stores, it returns something liks;
[ "A|B|C", "&H", "&", "D|E|F|G" ]
but what i want is something like 
["(A|B)", "(C|D)", (A|B)|(C|D)"]
not sure how clear this is, but yeah..

Answer (score 1):

so after researching a bit, i would say this is one solution on how to break up the string based on a mathematical logic.

```
$scope.array1 = [];
$scope.array2 = [];
var txt1 = "((A|B)|(C|D)) & (E | ((F|G) & (H|I))) & (J | K)";

for(var i=0; i < txt1.length; i++){
   if(txt1.charAt(i) === '('){
     $scope.array1.push(i);
   }
   if(txt1.charAt(i) === ')'){
     $scope.array2.push(txt1.substring($scope.array1.pop()+1,i));
   }
}
```

Hence, it array2 would return something like; 
["A|B", "C|D"] and so on.